# Equivalent method in Play 2.4 for Scope.Session

Tags: playframework

In old play framework we use Scope.Session.

What is the equivalent method in play framework 2.4 version?

Thanks.

Comment: Please add more info to your question. What is "old play"? v1? v2.x? Also provide an example of what you are trying to achieve

Comment: old version is play version 1

Comment: Post the code for your Play 1 where you use this session scope. It will make easier to understand how to port it to Play 2.4.

Answer (score 0):

For play 2.4 you can do it like:

Using scala:

```
Ok("Welcome!").withSession(
  "connected" -> "user@gmail.com")
```

as in the docs at https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaSessionFlash#Storing-data-into-the-Session

Using Java:

```
public Result login() {
    session("connected", "user@gmail.com");
    return ok("Welcome!");
}
```

as in the docs at 
https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/JavaSessionFlash#Storing-data-into-the-Session

Comment: I need to get the current session. example like Scope.Session is there any equivalent in 2.4.x as i am planning to write a session utility class